# After code change, how to start over debugging without restarting pdb?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdb

When debugging in pdb, I find an error and thus change the code.

Now I would like to start over debugging. Can I do that without exiting pdb, so that I don't have to specify the command line arguments to my python script? Or do I need to exit pdb and then enter it again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `run` pdb command, which stops the existing process and starts a new one.

You still have to specify the command-line arguments when running `run`, however, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands): "History, breakpoints, actions and debugger options are preserved".

If having to re-specify the command-line arguments is a problem, you can first print `' '.join(sys.argv)`, then copy-paste it to your `run` command (of course, further shell-escaping might be necessary).

Comment: Does `restart`  load and run the modified code instead of the old code?

Comment: @Tim docs say “restart” is an alias for “run”, meaning it does

Comment: I tried to specify args to `restart`, but pdb exits abnormally.

Comment: `run` sometimes works with args, but sometimes not. How does `restart` work for you for accepting args?

Comment: @Tim it doesn't, the docs are apparently wrong. I edited my answer